# Krajee bootstrap-fileinput and initialPreview issue if no image url set

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to show a initial avatar (uploaded before with the form), and display standard image (NO AVATAR) if avatar not exist? I uploaded an attachment: i want POINT 2 when i've uploaded nothing.

My input field:

```
<input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" data-url="<?php echo $path_to_actual_image; ?>">

// $path_to_actual_image can be empty if logo are not set yet
```

I use this now:

```
$("#avatar").fileinput({
  language: 'it',
  overwriteInitial: true,
  removeFromPreviewOnError: true,
  initialPreviewAsData: true,
    showClose: false,
    browseOnZoneClick: true,
    showCaption: false,
    browseIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>',
    removeIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
  initialPreview: [ function() { if ( $("#avatar").data("url") != "" ) { return $("#avatar").data("url"); } else { /*NOTHING*/ } ],
  defaultPreviewContent: '<img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no-avatar" alt="No avatar">',
  allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"],
    maxFileSize: 2000
})
```

It work good... but if no avatar exist, it show me a blank block! (POINT 1 of my uploaded example attachment) I tried to change in:

```
initialPreview: [ function() { if ( $("#avatarl").data("url") != "" )
{ return $("#avatar").val("url"); } else { return "http://www.placehold.it/300x300/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no-avatar"; } ]
```

...In this case I see standard image for no-avatar set, but zoom button and delete button are active!! (Those has to be not activate). (referring to POINT 4 in my attachment example[image])

Additional info: I not upload with ajax

Comment: did you solve the issue? or not?

Comment: No, still waiting for a solution